# error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway fatal

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push, bad-gateway

I was uploading code to my gitlabs repo and I'm receiving this error

```
Counting objects: 29295, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21490/21490), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29295/29295), 31.10 MiB | 167.62 MiB/s, done.
Total 29295 (delta 6225), reused 29295 (delta 6225)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Can't figure out how to solve this problem, please help out on this one.

Answer (score 3):

A 502 Bad Gateway error means that your request successfully sent a message to a proxy of some sort, but the server behind it was unable to be reached or sent an invalid response.  Like other 5xx errors, it indicates a server-side problem that the client cannot fix independently.

I believe GitLab, like many web apps, uses nginx in front of the main web app.  It's possible that the main web app has crashed, or some other problem has occurred, but regardless, you need to contact the administrator of your GitLab instance and ask them to fix the issue; there's nothing you can do to fix it.

If you're hosting your own GitLab instance, then I'd recommend making sure the services are running and viewing the logs to see what's gone wrong.

Comment: Ohh I'll try to contact gitlab and get back to you if that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using SSH , i guess if anyone faces this issues try cloning the repo using ssh and then try pushing the code :)